# Tab Order on Split Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a split form. As best as I can tell the top and the bottom are separate tab 'regions'
So if I click in the top, I tab around the top.  If I click in the bottom, I tab around the bottom.  The top has tabs 1-4 and the bottom has tabs 1-4

It there a way to make it a single set of tabs, 1-8 that would go from the top to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do this:

1. Create a (transparent and tiny) button in the header having *tabstop
   5*.
2. Add this code to the button for the *OnEnter* event:

```vb
Private Sub YourHeaderButton_Enter()
    Me!BottomTextbox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

3. Create a similar button in the footer.

Comment: Interesting way to get around the limitation.  Thanks

Comment: It's an old trick. Please mark as answered, if you feel so.